# Photoshop: Change pattern color gives me a washed out effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photo-editing, patterns, color-conversion

I'm trying to change the pattern color from a very light gray to a dark blue. I've used the  color blending mode, but the result is a washed out color. Is there anything I can do to have a  dark color result? Here is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly how you do it is based on your own sensibility, but a different approach for you:

Place a layer filled with black. Apply a layer effect of "color overlay" with light blue.

Above this, place another solid black layer with a layer mask. Apply a "color overlay" layer effect of dark blue to the layer.

Click on the layer mask to give it focus. Apply texture filter *to the mask* rather than the layer.

To tweak the colors, adjust the color overlays.

Note: You can use your grey texture as a basis for the layer mask: paste the existing image into the layer mask on the channels palette.

[image]